# ExpressionEngine custom extension to change date format

Tags: date, format, expressionengine

I am trying to create an Extension to change my entries formatting in the way I want , I can create my custom extension and change the date format using hooks , but I don't know where to use my custom hooks to change entries date format. I hope that I was clear enough! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you mean just changing the entry date etc on the front end (or do you mean something else)? Because you can change the format of output dates using http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but I meant changing the format in back end , because we have a way different format of showing date (I mean in my country) , different years and etc. I need to access the date insertion process to change it with a hook that I wrote for this conversion.

Comment: *** The only thing I need is to know where expressionengine insert date for channels so I can use my hook.

Comment: Dates are stored as UNIX timestamps for channel entries (no one uses them in their country). Don't try to mess with the date insertion process, you'll break everything. You're approaching this from the wrong angle. You're wanting to change how the date is displayed in the front/back end right? Front end is easy, run it through your own parser when you output it in a template. Back end will involve hacking the core channel entries table output.

Comment: You're right JamesNZ  , I decided to write a module to enable this feature using back end control panel , which will take the entry date field and return the custom formatted date , how does this sound?